# Drop into interpreter during arbitrary scala code location

Tags: debugging, scala, interpreter

I come from a Python background, where at any point in my code I can add

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

and at runtime I'll be dropped into an interactive interpreter at that spot. Is there an equivalent for scala, or is this not possible at runtime?

Comment: In the spirit of "truth in advertising," Scala has no interpreter. Its REPL is "compile-and-go." That said, the REPL code (including the compiler) can be incorporated into your application, if you wish (as shown below)

Comment: But the REPL will launch without any knowledge of your running context except for what you explicitly and laboriously bind in your REPL-launching code. See below. I think in python you land into the running context which is much better. anyway, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674288/clean-solution-for-dropping-into-repl-console-in-the-middle-of-program-execution?lq=1 is more up-to-date.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yes, you can, on Scala 2.8. Note that, for this to work, you have to include the scala-compiler.jar in your classpath. If you invoke your scala program with `scala`, it will be done automatically (or so it seems in the tests I made).

You can then use it like this:

```
import scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter._

object TestDebugger {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    0 to 10 foreach { i =>
      breakIf(i == 5, DebugParam("i", i))
      println(i)
    }
  }
}
```

You may pass multiple `DebugParam` arguments. When the REPL comes up, the value on the right will be bound to a val whose name you provided on the left. For instance, if I change that line like this:

```
      breakIf(i == 5, DebugParam("j", i))
```

Then the execution will happen like this:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Scala\Programas>scala TestDebugger
0
1
2
3
4
j: Int

scala> j
res0: Int = 5
```

You continue the execution by typing `:quit`.

You may also unconditionally drop into REPL by invoking `break`, which receives a `List` of `DebugParam` instead of a vararg. Here's a full example, code and execution:

```
import scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter._

object TestDebugger {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    0 to 10 foreach { i =>
      breakIf(i == 5, DebugParam("j", i))
      println(i)
      if (i == 7) break(Nil)
    }
  }
}
```

And then:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Scala\Programas>scalac TestDebugger.scala

C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Scala\Programas>scala TestDebugger
0
1
2
3
4
j: Int

scala> j
res0: Int = 5

scala> :quit
5
6
7

scala> j
<console>:5: error: not found: value j
       j
       ^

scala> :quit
8
9
10

C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Scala\Programas>
```

Comment: This may lead to an error `scala.tools.nsc.MissingRequirementError: object scala not found.` in Scala 2.8. You may need to explicitly pass the classpath of the host process to the Settings of Scalac, but `break` and `breakIf` don't do this. Here's a patched version of `break` that does: http://gist.github.com/290632

Comment: @retronym Funny, it just worked here. Send it to paulp. He mentioned this thing was going to be changed anyway.

Comment: I tried it from a JUnit test, run by IntelliJ. IntelliJ launched the process with `java -classpath ...`. I guess if you use `scala -classpath` instead it would work fine.

Comment: @retronym If you are launching it from JUnit, then you have to add the scala-compiler.jar to the classes in the library of the project structure, I suppose. I said you needed to add it to the classpath.

Comment: It was a dependency of the module, and hence in the classpath. 2.8 doesn't pass the contents of `java -classpath` of the host process to the settings for scalac: http://old.nabble.com/-scala--recent-changes-in-2.8-nightly-classpath-management-td26233977.html

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind, but it doesn't compile for me in Scala 2.7.5final. Is this new to Scala 2.8?

    TestDebugger.scala:6: error: not found: value breakIf
          breakIf(i == 5, DebugParam("j", i))
          ^
    one error found

Comment: @Lars Yes, it is only available on Scala 2.8. Sorry for not indicating that in the answer.

Comment: I am running the example in Scala 2.8 but I get the following exception. Do you have any idea on how could I fix that?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/io/LowPriorityCodecImplicits

Comment: Actually the issue is with Eclipse, running it from the command line makes it perform as desired.

Comment: I still get the error @retronym mentioned a long time ago.  I'm using 2.9.1.

Comment: I get the error with `mvn exec:java` or `java -cp`.  I don't get the error when running a fat jar with `scala -cp`.

Comment: Strange, I think I used to have this working, but it's now hanging for me on Scala 2.9.1

Comment: What about for Scala 2.10 and above (scala.reflect.universe._ was added)?

Comment: @Huur See [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19070053/53013) by [Răzvan Panda](http://stackoverflow.com/users/750216/rzvan-panda).

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Sorry, for not noticing that. I'll check it out later tonight.

Answer (score 25):

To add to Daniel's answer, as of Scala 2.9, the `break` and `breakIf` methods are contained in `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop`. Also, `DebugParam` is now `NamedParam`.

Comment: You will need to add [jline](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/jline/2.9.1) as a dependency.

Comment: can you please write an example with the new usage?

Answer (score 25):

**IntelliJ IDEA:**

1. Run in debug mode or attach a remote debugger
2. Set a breakpoint and run until you reach it
3. Open `Evaluate Expression` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, in menu: Run -> Evaluate Expression) window to run arbitrary Scala code.
4. Type what code fragment or expression you want to run and click on Evaluate
5. Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or click on Evaluate to run the code fragment.

[image]

**Eclipse:**

As of Scala 2.10 both `break` and `breakIf` have been removed from `ILoop`.

To break into interpreter you will have to work with `ILoop` directly.

First add `scala compiler` library. For Eclipse Scala, right click on project => `Build Path` => `Add Libraries...` => `Scala Compiler`.

And then you can use the following where you want to start the interpreter:

```
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.SimpleReader
import scala.tools.nsc.Settings

val repl = new ILoop
repl.settings = new Settings
repl.settings.Yreplsync.value = true
repl.in = SimpleReader()
repl.createInterpreter()

// bind any local variables that you want to have access to
repl.intp.bind("row", "Int", row)
repl.intp.bind("col", "Int", col)

// start the interpreter and then close it after you :quit
repl.loop()
repl.closeInterpreter()
```

In Eclipse Scala the interpreter can be used from the `Console` view:

[image]

Comment: @Daniel Why is that horrible?

Comment: Because it adds a lot of boiler-plate which is completely unrelated to the goal of debugging at a point in the program, and, instead, related to the mechanics of getting the REPL going.

Comment: @Daniel is there any better way in scala 2.10 ?

Comment: @roterl What is the problem with the above?

Comment: @Daniel you wrote "That's horrible. :( "  with explanation why. I agree with that.  But is there a better way?

Comment: @roterl I really don't know. I assume there isn't. I said it was horrible because, well, it was really neat before, not because I thought there was a better way.

Comment: In Scala 2.11.6 this produces a runtime error `object scala in compiler mirror not found.`

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I updated the answer to be less terrible (for IntelliJ IDEA at least) :)

Comment: This could be used to create a REPL debugger that could be included in a Scala project, much like Pry.  I have a feeling the explicit 'break' functionality was removed because the core contributors of the Scala languages felt having a built-in way of dropping into a REPL to debug Scala was less flexible and would stunt innovation on better debugging tools (and it's really also scope-creep for designing the language itself).