# How do I embed the Scala 2.8 interpreter in a Java application?

Tags: scala

I want to be be able to manipulate objects in memory in my Java app interactively for debugging purposes.  I would quite like to do this using Scala's 2.8 interpreter, taking advantages of its features like tab-completion.  How do I do this?

Comment: Are you looking to break into the REPL mid-execution (based on some condition), run the REPL in parallel on a separate thread, connect to a remote VM, or just pull your project into scope on the REPL classpath?

Comment: Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160355/drop-into-interpreter-during-arbitrary-scala-code-location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Josh Suereth's [Embedding the Scala Interpreter](http://suereth.blogspot.com/2009/04/embedding-scala-interpreter.html).

> You can see the auto-complete suggestions below.

```
josh@suereth-desktop:~/projects/blog/embed-the-interpreter$ java -jar target/embedded-interpreter-0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
Welcome to Awesomeness!
This is my version of the Scala interpreter
TestInterpreter> j

java javax jline
```

I think he also implemented the feature into Scala IDE for Eclipse so you also take a look at that. The latest is [available online](http://www.assembla.com/code/scala-ide/git/nodes/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/src/scala/tools/eclipse/interpreter?rev=HEAD).

I wanted to run Scala code as part of testing, so I've implemented [CompilerMatcher](http://github.com/eed3si9n/scalaxb/blob/master/src/test/scala/CompilerMatcher.scala) following his article.

Comment: Unfortunately as of now, that link requires signing up to blogger and getting an invitation to the blog.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of providing an embedded scala 2.9.1 over ssh: [scala-ssh-shell](https://github.com/peak6/scala-ssh-shell)