# How to write Scala 2.9 code that will allow dropping into an interpreter

Tags: debugging, scala, interpreter

I am not sure how to write code that will allow dropping into an interpreter into Scala 2.9 code. This question is a follow-up to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160355/drop-into-interpreter-during-arbitrary-scala-code-location), which asked what the Scala equivalent of,

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

was from Python.  The advice given there was primarily for Scala 2.8, and the related packages no longer exist in their previous form.  Namely,

1. `scala.nsc.tools.nsc.Interpreter.{break, breakIf}` have been moved to `scala.nsc.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.{break, breakIf}`
2. `DebugParam` is now `NamedParam` in scala.tools.nsc.interpreter

As noted in the original post, the class path of the parent process is not passed to the new interpreter automatically, so a workaround was presented [here](https://gist.github.com/290632).  Unfortunately, many of the classes/methods invoked there have now changed, and I'm not quite sure how to modify the code the behave as "expected".

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is my test code, which at current compiles and runs, but attempting to execute anything in the debugger results in the application freezing if compiled by `scalac` and executed by `scala`

```
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop._

object Main extends App {

  case class C(a: Int, b: Double, c: String) {
    def throwAFit(): Unit = {
      println("But I don't wanna!!!")
    }
  }

  // main
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val c = C(1, 2.0, "davis")

    0.until(10).foreach {
      i => 
        println("i = " + i)
        breakIf(i == 5)
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT2:  As my current setup is running through sbt, I have discovered that this topic is covered [in the FAQ](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/FAQ) (bottom of the page).  However, I do not understand the explanation given, and any clarification on `MyType` would be invaluable.

EDIT3: another discussion on the topic without a solution: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.simple-build-tool/1622

Comment: I've run into this as well tonight.  Even: object Main extends App { scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.breakIf(true) } will hang.

Answer (score 3):

So I know this is an old question, but if your REPL is hanging, I wonder if the problem is that [you need to supply the `-Yrepl-sync` option](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/simple-build-tool/APF5m23jWcQ/_NpUa7YAKIcJ)? When my embedded REPL was hanging in a similar situation, that solved it for me.

To set `-Yrepl-sync` in an embedded REPL, instead of using `breakIf` you'll need to [work with the `ILoop` directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939732/alternative-to-scala-repl-breakif-in-2-10/13250327#13250327) so you can access the `Settings` object:

```
// create the ILoop
val repl = new ILoop
repl.settings = new Settings
repl.in = SimpleReader()

// set the "-Yrepl-sync" option
repl.settings.Yreplsync.value = true

// start the interpreter and then close it after you :quit
repl.createInterpreter()
repl.loop()
repl.closeInterpreter()
```

Comment: This solution indeed worked for me for the problem that OP had. You can even write your own `break` and `breakIf` this way.