# Alternative to Scala REPL breakIf in 2.10

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I was reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160355/drop-into-interpreter-during-arbitrary-scala-code-location) about using the `breakIf` method in the REPL code for interactive debugging, but then I found [this post](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6435) saying that `break` and `breakIf` were removed from `ILoop` in Scala 2.10. Unfortunately, that post doesn't explain *why* the code was removed.

I'm assuming that these functions were removed because there's a better way of doing this. If that's the case, could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Why not just put a breakpoint in Eclipse and have it stop there, as you can give it conditions.

Comment: @James Black - Yes, if I'm using Eclipse that's an option. However, I really doubt that's why this functionality was removed from the 2.10 codebase.

Comment: You could look in the repository perhaps, as when it was removed, and see if they put in a reason.

Comment: @James Black - There's a link to the commit in the post linked to above. It was removed as part of a large commit (affecting a lot of files) with the commit message "Removing more unneeded code."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the idea is that you should just work with the `ILoop` directly? As far as I can tell, it shouldn't be much more complex than:

```
// insert the code below wherever you want a REPL
val repl = new ILoop
repl.settings = new Settings
repl.in = SimpleReader()
repl.createInterpreter()

// bind any local variables that you want to have access to
repl.intp.bind("i", "Int", i)
repl.intp.bind("e", "Exception", e)

// start the interpreter and then close it after you :quit
repl.loop()
repl.closeInterpreter()
```

Compared to the old `breakIf` API, this approach gets rid of an additional level of indirection for both the `if` condition (which was wrapped into a `=> Boolean`) and the `DebugParam`/`NamedParam` (which were temporary wrappers used only to fill in the `bind` arguments).

This approach also allows you to specify your `Settings` as needed. For example, [some REPL bugs can be worked around with `-Yrepl-sync` but `break` gave you no way of specifying that](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simple-build-tool/APF5m23jWcQ/_NpUa7YAKIcJ).

Comment: So the answer is that they want us to re-implement it ourselves?

Comment: Well, I can't speak for the Scala developers. But one answer could be that it wasn't flexible enough to be used as-is (e.g. if you needed `-Yrepl-sync`), and making it more flexible would have made it as complicated just writing the code itself.

Comment: That said, some better default for `ILoop.settings` and `ILoop.in` would make the above code much more palatable. I'm not at all bothered by the `createInterpreter`, `bind`, `loop` or `closeInterpreter` calls, since these are exactly what we're trying to accomplish here. But having to set `var`s on the ILoop feels wrong.

Comment: Initially, when I tried the above code in 2.10.2 the interpreter hung. What got it working for me was adding `repl.settings.Yreplsync.value = true`